# Is there a way to add dapper queries to a list and execute all?

Tags: c#, list, dapper

I am using Dapper to execute queries to the database. I was wondering if there is a way to make a list that contains multiple methods and execute them by looping through them. I include two methods that show the queries, I am using. I have another method that connects to the database where it calls the methods.

```
private void DeleteCar(SqlConnection connection, string databaseName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"Starting Delete for CarInfo for {databaseName}");

    connection.Query($"DELETE FROM dbo.CarInfo WHERE ParentCarId IS NULL OR ParentDriverId IS NULL");
}

private void DeleteHouse(SqlConnection connection, string databaseName)
{
    Console.WriteLine($@"Starting Delete for HouseInfo for {databaseName}");

    connection.Query($"DELETE FROM dbo.HouseInfo WHERE ParentHouseId IS NULL OR ParentOwnerId IS NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Dapper *does* have a facility for this when issuing the same query *against multiple inputs*, by passing an `IEnumerable<T>` as the parameters object - it essentially unrolls it internally as though you had issued a `foreach` using each item in turn - but for *different* queries: no, just issue them one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use table type in your stored procedures, so in c# you can create a model like this:

```cs
public class IntIdTableType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then with your connection you can do something like:

```cs
connection.QueryAsync<myViewModel>("[dbo].[spName]", param: new
    {
        ((List<IntIdTableType>)model.YourIListPropertyModel).ToDataTable(),
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Then in your SQL create table type

```
CREATE TYPE intHelper AS TABLE
( 
    Id INT
)
```

And finally in your stored procedure in your params:

```
    @MyIdTableType [intHelper] READONLY
```

Query:

```sql
    DELETE FROM dbo.HouseInfo WHERE ParentHouseId IS NULL OR ParentOwnerId IS NULL AND SomeColumn IN (@MyIdTableType)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Action for every method but the actions need to have the same prototype (arguments). An action is equivalent to a pointer to a function. Here I initialize the actions with lambdas for simplicity.

Once you have your array of actions, you can just loop through it and call them one by one.

```
    var methods = new List<Action<SqlConnection, string>>
    {
        (connection,databaseName) => DeleteCar(connection, databaseName),
        (connection,databaseName) => DeleteHouse(connection, databaseName),
    };

    SqlConnection myDb;
    string dbName;

    foreach (var action in methods)
    {
        action(myDb, dbName);
    }
```

I can also initialize the array directly with method groups

```
    var methods = new List<Action<SqlConnection, string>>
    {
        DeleteCar,
        DeleteHouse,
    };
```

The difference is with method groups you give directly the method and with lambda you could tweak parameters (like giving always the same dbName):

```
    string dbName = "toto"; 
    var methods = new List<Action<SqlConnection, string>>
    {
        (connection) => DeleteCar(connection, dbName),
        (connection) => DeleteHouse(connection, dbName),
    };

    SqlConnection myDb;

    foreach (var action in methods)
    {
        action(myDb);
    }
```

Comment: that seems like an overly complicated way of calling two methods, IMHO...

Comment: @marc-gravell Indeed it's complicated. However as the question was related to putting methods into list, I assume there are plenty of other methods... Anyway, it's more like a proof of concept rather than something to do in real life.